# p.close and p.join in multiporcessing.Pool

Tags: python

I am following an instruction from youtube to learn multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess
import time

def f(n):
    sum = 0
    for x in range(1000):
        sum += x*x
    return sum

if __name__ == "__main__":

    t1 = time.time()
    p = Pool()
    result = p.map(f, range(10000))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("Pool took: ", time.time()-t1)
```

I am puzzled about `p.close()` and `p.join()`

when processes were closed, they did not exist any more, how could manipulate `.join` to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join()` waits for a child process to be killed. Killed processes send a signal informing their parents that they are quite dead. `close()` doesn't kill any process, It just closes a pipe which informs readers of that pipe, that there will be no more data coming through it.